# Can I cite a Compiled Query as the Data Source to a Compiled Query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Best to describe this in code...

I have this

```
public class A<T>
{
     public static class Queries
     {
          public static Func<DataContext, int, T>Get =
                CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, int, T>(
                    (DataContextdb, int i) => (from t in db.GetTable<T>()
                                                      where t.ID == i
                                                      select t).SingleOrDefault());
     }
}
```

Can I create a new class and query, like this...

```
public class B<T>:A<t>
{
      public static class BQueries
      {
          public static Func<DataContext, int, T> Get =
              CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, int, T>(
                  (DataContext db, int id) => (from t in A.Queries.Get(db, id)
                                               where !t.Item.Deleted 
                                               select t).SingleOrDefault());
      }

      public abstract TrackingItem Item;
}
```

All I want to do is compile a new query based on the original that adds a couple constraints. This is in lieu of executing two queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work if `A.Queries.Get(...)` returned an `IQueryable<>`, but as written your code returns a `T`. However, if you remove `SingleOrDefault()` it should work fine.

**Update:** For good measure, this code should work:

```
public static class Queries
{
    public static Func<DataContext, int, IQueryable<T>>Get =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, int, IQueryable<T>>(
            (DataContext db, int i) => from t in db.GetTable<T>()
                                       where t.ID == i
                                       select t);
}

public static class BQueries
{
    public static Func<DataContext, int, IQueryable<T>> Get =
        CompiledQuery.Compile<DataContext, int, IQueryable<T>>(
            (DataContext db, int id) => from t in A.Queries.Get(db, id)
                                        where !t.Item.Deleted 
                                        select t);
}
```

The queries won't actually execute until you call an immediate operator like `SingleOrDefault()`:

```
using(var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var res = BQueries.Get(db, id);
    var entity = res.SingleOrDefault();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah I see now... that makes sense. I was shooting for deferred execution. Does it even make sense to compile SingleOrDefault into a query?

Comment: It's always a tradeoff between usability and the performance cost of parsing the expression. I tend to defer as long as possible, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: Defering execution until last possible moment it my goal here. Is adding SingleOrDefault to the compiled query causing it to execute the minute the query is referenced?

Comment: Yes, adding any immediate operator to the end of a compiled query means you'll have a delegate that immediately executes when invoked with the DataContext.